# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - query result as text

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database in Microsoft SQL Server and I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I have an option to insert the query result to the file, although the results of the query are not separated by any special signs.

It looks like this

```
select * from table_name
```

Output:

```
18 182 3386 NULL
18 790 12191 NULL
```

In File:

```
18          182         3386        NULL
18          790         12191       NULL
```

Is there any possibility to modify query so after every record it will put a special char, like this:

In File:

```
18;          182;         3386;        NULL;
18;          790;         12191;       NULL;
```

It will be easier then for me to copy this database to other programs.

Comment: <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Find and Replace</kbd> > Regex replace `\t` with `;\t` and `\n` with `\n;`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In SSMS:

`Tools` > `Options` > `Query Results` > `Results To Text`

Top option there is `Output Format`, can set a delimiter there.

Comment: For a screenshot of how to choose the delimiter for the text output, see [Custom delimiter in SQL Server set in "Results to Text" options doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54853827/11154841).

Answer (score 40):

[image: Click here]

Click here on your SSMS before you execute your query.

Comment: This is what I had accidentally hit! Hart CO's answer was set correctly in my options but the button above was toggled to text response.

Answer (score 9):

CTRL+T Then Execute , = Text Result
CTRL+D Then Execute , = Grid Result

Comment: This is what I needed! For some reason it seems that if you used the key commands (which I did by mistake), setting through Query Results in Tools doesn't fix it. I had to use CTRL+D to get out of text results.