# Custom delimiter in SQL Server set in "Results to Text" options doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, delimiter

I am interested in saving the result of a SQL query, like a `SELECT` statement, as a pipe (`|`) delimited text file in SSMS.

I can do that using the **Export wizard**.

However, it seems there's a simpler method by setting a "Custom delimiter" in `Tools>Options` under `Query Results>SQL Server>Results to Text` as shown here:
[image]

Then, if I specify `"Results to Text"` or `"Results to File"`, I am supposed to get the pipe delimited result.

This is also outlined here:[Obtaining Pipe Delimited Results from SQL Server using SSMS](https://mssqltrek.com/2012/07/24/obtaining-pipe-delimited-results-from-sql-server-using-ssms/)

But, doing this I still get the usual output with either Results to Text or File.

I don't know what I'm missing or doing wrong.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's not perfectly clear for me what is you problem exactly but if I remember correcty - SSMS sometimes needs to restart for activation of some of the settings. So, classical: "Have you tried turning it off and on?"

Comment: Just to re-iterate what @AlexYu said: changes to query related options do not affect existing queries, only new queries.

Comment: @AlexYu Thank you. Restarting SSMS actually did the trick. I'm now properly embarrassed to have asked this as my first question here, before trying "turning it off and on"! Should I delete the whole thing you think?

Comment: I'm not sure about deleting this post. And I think there is nothing to be embarassed about - because I saw this a lot of times when worked with MSSQL. I suggest it would be better to answer your own post and accept it. Explain clearly that was "turning off and on" case and maybe this post will be helpful in future for others. Although I suggest that you add information about SSMS version - who knows maybe MS will correct this "bug" in future. And again - there is nothing to be ashamed.

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @Alex It's not even for "new queries". Some settings such as text buffer size (if I remember correctly) comes into effect only after restart of SSMS. I mean: one can't just reopen new session - whole IDE needs to be restarted

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @AlexYu, the answer is simply applying the "turning it off and on" trick. Closing and re-opening SSMS is required before the change in this setting takes effect.

Incidentally, disconnecting and re-connecting to the SQL server doesn't work in this case. I have done some rudimentary tests and it seems this also applies to other options here, for example under `Query Results>SQL Server>Results to Grid`.

I was using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v17.9.1, build number 14.0.17289.0.

Answer (score 1):

I think "Query Results" **is able to delimit the results by a custom character, only if all the datatype is varchar**. I did what you wrote in the description and additionally I casted all the columns to varchar.

```
SELECT TOP (1000)  CAST([COL_A] as varchar) as 'COL_A'
  ,CAST([COL_B] as varchar) as 'COL_B'
  ,CAST([COL_C] as varchar) as 'COL_C'
FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: Is this not just a placebo answer? You likely just "turned it off and on again" in the meantime, as in the other answer?

Comment: Hello @questionto42, as I wrote, you may run into problems if you don't convert all data types to varchar. My answer is an addition to the answers given by other people. For me the custom delimiter was not applied before casting to varchar all data type