# How to avoid create view must be the only statement in the batch error?

Tags: sql-server

`CREATE VIEW` part is highlighted as an error and I can not run full code at once(it shows me errors) and how to avoid this?

```
-- Creating pizza view
CREATE VIEW pizza_view
AS
SELECT p.pizza_id
    ,p.pizza_name
    ,p.description AS 'pizza_desc'
    ,t.type_id AS 'range_id'
    ,t.type_name AS 'range_name'
    ,t.price AS 'range_price'
FROM pizza AS p
INNER JOIN type AS t ON p.type_id = t.type_id;

-- Creating side view
CREATE VIEW side_view
AS
SELECT so.order_id
    ,so.side_id
    ,s.side_name
    ,so.qty_ordered AS 'qty'
    ,s.price * so.qty_ordered AS 'total_cost'
FROM side AS s
INNER JOIN side_order AS so ON s.side_id = so.side_id;

-- Creating order view
CREATE VIEW order_view
AS
SELECT p.pizza_id
    ,po.order_id
    ,co.ready
    ,p.pizza_name
    ,t.type_id AS 'range_id'
    ,t.type_name AS 'range_name'
    ,t.price + i.surcharge AS 'cost_of_the_pizza'
FROM pizza AS p
INNER JOIN type AS t ON p.type_id = t.type_id
INNER JOIN pizza_order AS po ON p.pizza_id = po.pizza_id
INNER JOIN customer_order AS co ON po.order_id = co.order_id
INNER JOIN pizza_ingredient AS pi ON p.pizza_id = pi.pizza_id
INNER JOIN ingredient AS i ON pi.ingredient_id = i.ingredient_id;
```

Comment: *it shows me errors*: please share the error message that you are getting.

Comment: try with GO statements after every CREATE VIEW

Comment: i found my error thank you i have put a ; after the go (GO;) that is why it didnt work after i use the go.

Comment: @xxdsxx You can try and run one by one your query also.

Comment: @Suraj Kumar previously i did it like that but i needed to run the full code at once

Comment: @xxdsxx You need to set separator as Go in SSMS. Please check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853827/custom-delimiter-in-sql-server-set-in-results-to-text-options-doesnt-work

Comment: @xxdsxx When using Go you do not need to use semicolon (;) at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to correct two issues like separation and different names for different views. As the error is giving query for creating a view, stored procedure and function should be in the separate batch.

GO signals the end of a batch of Transact-SQL statements to the SQL Server utilities.

For example:

```
Create view <YourViewName>
Select * from <YourViewName> -- This will give error.
```

It is because both statements is in the same batch.

```
-- Creating pizza view
CREATE VIEW pizza_view1
AS
SELECT 1 AS a --Your actual view statement here.
GO

-- Creating side view
CREATE VIEW side_view2
AS
SELECT 2 AS b --Your actual view statement here.
GO

-- Creating order view
CREATE VIEW order_view3
AS
SELECT 3 AS c --Your actual view statement here.
```

You can find the [Documentation of Go here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Just a reminder to @xxdsxx and anyone else finding this, that "GO" is not a SQL statement, it's a separator recognized by clients like SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and other SQL Tools (OSQL.EXE, SQLCMD.EXE, etc). If you're executing this from your own code, you need to submit three separate batches, each "CREATE VIEW" in its own batch request. This is what these other utilities do under the covers... "GO" is just a "batch separator".

Comment: @pmbAustin You are right and as per the setting in the SSMS or maybe other editors Go can be changed into some other text also.