# Save an SQL message into a file

Tags: sql, database

How to save the messages into a file that appear after running a query like '1 row affected' directly through a query?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please elaborate on your question about what software you are using, if it is a GUI based SQL or terminal based so that I can answer the question to your needs.

Comment: If SQL Server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20012552/microsoft-sql-server-management-studio-query-result-as-text

Comment: Hi, it is SQL server

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Which Database do you use?

With an Oracle database you can use "spool".

Example:

```
spool 'Path to your file'

{your update / insert statement here}

spool off
```

Comment: Hi, it is SQL server